# Add textbox into header or footer into GridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm making a Windows Forms project in C#, but I don't know how to add a control like `TextBox` into the header or footer of a `GridView`.

I'm looking for my `GridView` to look something like this, with editable boxes below each header for searching.

```
|    ID     |     Name    |     Age    |
| search ID | search Name | search Age |
________________________________________
|    1      |    TOM      |     15     |
|   ...     |    ...      |     ...    |
```

Comment: Too broad -- post some code and show us where you are stuck.

Comment: When you say `GridView` in the context of Windows Forms, I assumed you meant `DataGridView` and added that tag. Is that true?